# Lightning Web component add an extra DOM element

Tags: lightning-web-components

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_html): "*When a component renders, the  tag is replaced with the name of the component,  . For example, in the browser console, a component with the template myComponent.html renders as  `<c-my-component>`, where c is the default namespace.*"

This way, lwc is adding an extra tag in my DOM. Example:

```
 <tbody>
    <c-my-component>
      some content
    </c-my-component>
</tbody>
```

Is there a way to avoid adding that extra tag and just put the content? Ex:

```
<tbody>
  some content
</tbody>
```

Basically, I looking for an equivalent to React Fragment
https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't remove that extra element, but at least it possible mitigate the styles issues adding in the parent component a rule like:

```
c-my-component {
    display: contents;
}
```

[Display contents](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) makes the container disappear, making the child elements children of the element the next level up in the DOM
It doesn't work on IE11

Answer (score 5):

No. The "extra" element is required for DOM/CSS/event isolation. In LWC, *all* elements participate in a "closed Shadow DOM" model. Whatever you're trying to do will require a different approach in LWC.

Comment: I have a table, and each row is a child component. In this case, that extra element is breaking my table...

Comment: @CarlosIribar You should be able to do so with some CSS within the LWC model. The general idea is that you'd want to use `:host()` to fix the display mode for the component.

Comment: Not working with select because of extra wrapper element on option.
`<c-select-option c-selectoption_selectoption-host="">
<option>sdfsdf</option>
</c-select-option>`